# Does NVIDIA Docker need CUDA installed?

Tags: docker, cuda, nvidia

I am setting up my environment for machine learning development and I thought of using Docker.

Does Nvidia CUDA and/or CUdnn need to be installed on my machine or does it work only by existing in the docker container?

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need:

- the nvidia driver
- a recent version of docker-ce (19.03 or newer)
- and the [nvidia container toolkit](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker) also called "nvidia docker"

You generally do not need CUDA (toolkit) or CUDNN installed on the base machine.  Those can be in the container for use in the container.

See [here](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker) for specific install instructions.